# What day does a week start?

Tags: discussion, stackexchange

What is the beginning of a week in SO?

I know days are Midnight to Midnight UTC, but what is a week? I only ask that so I know whether I could overtake Mikołaj Bartnicki on the rep weekly leagues.

Comment: Should be moved to Meta Stack Overflow...

Answer (score 3):

On the [user leagues](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/31/week/askubuntu/2014-07-27/186134#186134) page, it says Jul 27, 2014 - Aug 1, 2014.

[image]

My calendar says that July 27 was a Sunday.

[image]

So I'm guessing SO use Sunday as the first day of the week :)

Keeping to [the creation story](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/2305/11411) I see (Sunday the first day)!

<sub>Yep the first image is self promotion :P</sub>

My pronouns are He / Him